# Running program from debug folder doesn't read input from file while on compile with VS2010 in runs properly

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, input, file-io

So i have a program which reads the input out of a specific .txt file. The code is:

```
void Image::get_image_dimensions(char *fname)
{
// determine the number of entries in image
ifstream fin(fname);
fin >> num_rows ;
fin >> num_columns ;
cout << "...reading from file " << fname << endl;
cout << "File has " << num_columns << " rows and "<<  num_columns << " columns" << endl;
fin.close();

}
```

the method is called inside the main.
After I compile the program with VS2010 and run the code everything works properly. But after if I go to the Debug folder of my program and run my program from there it doesn't read the input anymore, and crashes...

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current directory is different in the two cases. The best solution is to provide the full path to the file, not just the file name.